# Critical confusion with the spectrum and resolvent of a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I know that the spectrum of a compact operator $C$ consists at most of countable set of complex number that accumulates only at $0$. I also know that the resolvent $(\lambda-C)^{-1}$ has a pole at each nonzero element of the spectrum.

Here I meet a serious contradiction. The complex analysis says an analytic function cannot have an infinite (even countable) number of poles in a bounded domain. However, is it possible that a compact operator $C$ has an infinite spectrum so that the poles of the resolvent are infinite in number? I am extremely confused...

Answer (score 2):

We can have an infinite number of poles in a finite region. $\frac  1 {\sin (\frac 1 z)}$ has a pole at each of the points $\frac 1 {n\pi}$.

Note: $0$ is not a  pole of the resolvent  and there is no disc around it on which the resolvent is analytic except at $0$. So having  poles tending to $0$ is not  a contradiction to the result you are quoting.

Comment: The Churchill complex variables and application book has an exercise 11 in p.247 that if $R$ is a region inside and on a simple closed contour and $f$ is analytic on $R$ except for poles in the interior of $R$, then $f$ must have at most finite poles.

Comment: Then is this exercise wrong?

Comment: @Keith In that result a crucial hypothesis is that the singualirities are **isolated**.  Here that condition is not satisfied.

Comment: But poles are by definition isolated singularities.

Comment: That is the point. In your question about a compact operator you cannot assume that  the resolvent is analytic except for poles. So Churchill's result is not applicable here.

Comment: The resolvent is analytic on the resolvent set. And the spectrum is just the complement of the resolvent set. And the resolvent has poles at nonzero elements of the spectrum. Then I think $0$ is the issue.

Comment: Precisely. There is no contradiction in having a sequence of poles approaching $0$, but you cannot have poles approaching any other number.

Comment: But Churchill's exercise does not seem to discriminate $0$.

Comment: 1) If the spectrum of a compact operator does not contain $0$ then I think the spectrum must be finite. So there is no problem

Comment: Once you include $0$ in the domain  you no longer have isolated poles so there is no contradiction with what Chuchill is saying.

Comment: That is where I am confused about. As far as I know, poles are by definition isolated.

Comment: So I think if $0$ is contained in the spectrum, then the resolvent must have some more severe singularity at $0$. If so, I think things are settled...

Comment: @Keith I don't know about "more severe", but yes, if $0$ is in the spectrum then $0$ is certainly _not_ a pole of the resolvent, since it's not a _isolated_  singularity.

Comment: Yes I was sloppy in expression. What you said is exactly what I mean.